# Backup MySQL users

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, migration, backup

How do I backup MySQL users and their privileges?

Anything like mysqldump?

I am looking for something like:

```
mysqldump -d -u root -p MyTable > Schema.sql
```

Answer (score 43):

```
mysql -BNe "select concat('\'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\'') from mysql.user where user != 'root'" | \
while read uh; do mysql -BNe "show grants for $uh" | sed 's/$/;/; s/\\\\/\\/g'; done > grants.sql
```

Answer (score 31):

You can backup mysql database using

```
mysqldump -u root -p mysql > mysql.sql
```

and restore mysql database by executing

```
 mysql -uroot -p mysql < mysql.sql
```

Dont forget to

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

after restoring dump.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks! After the `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` command, it all started working

Comment: This is the better answer because it includes the flush privileges command. Another alternative is to just restart the server process instead of flushing privileges.

Comment: This is only guranteed to work if restoring to the same MySQL version, the the 'mysql' database may differ accross versions and contains many more things than just users/privileges. If your intention is to migrate your users and privileges to another server, @spirit 's answer above is the way to go.

Answer (score 14):

So far my experience with MySQL i didn't see anything to backup user and their privileges through a command line.

But i can backup those critical data by backing up mysql

```
mysqldump -u root -p mysql > mysql.sql
```

Comment: how should this be restored? is it just by executing the resulting file on the information_schema??

Answer (score 9):

Percona has a great tool for this. `pt-show-grants` will dump users and their permissions so you can easily reload them.

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-show-grants.html

Comment: This worked beautifully, and dumped hashed passwords unlike the other solutions.  Use `--ignore` to skip grants for certain users, or `--only` to only include grants for certain users.  Option syntax differs from `mysqldump` in that `--ask-pass` is its own option.

Answer (score 6):

The users and privileges are stored in the databased named 'mysql'.  You can use mysqldump to backup the tables in the databased named 'mysql'.

Comment: can you add how to restore those?

Answer (score 1):

Good practice is using script for daily backup MySQL users and their privileges.
Take take a look on a one:

```
#!/bin/sh

HOSTNAME="localhost"

mysql -h $HOSTNAME -B -N -e "SELECT CONCAT('\'', user,'\'@\'', host, '\'') FROM user WHERE user != 'debian-sys-maint' AND user != 'root' AND user != ''" mysql > mysql_all_users_$HOSTNAME.txt

while read line; do mysql -h $HOSTNAME -B -N -e "SHOW GRANTS FOR $line"; done < mysql_all_users_$HOSTNAME.txt > mysql_all_users_$HOSTNAME.sql

sed -i.bak 's/$/;/' mysql_all_users_$HOSTNAME.sql

rm mysql_all_users_$HOSTNAME.txt
rm mysql_all_users_$HOSTNAME.sql.bak
```

Result of this script will be mysqldump file with users and privileges.

P.S. If your MySQL requires password - put `-p` or `-u username -p` after `mysql -h $HOSTNAME` in two places.

Answer (score 0):

probably pretty obvious for mysql command liners but for @spirit's answer above had to add -u root -ppassword after both mysql commands

> mysql -u root -ppassword -BNe "select concat(''',user,''@'',host,''') from mysql.user where user != 'root'" | while read uh; do mysql -u root -ppassword -BNe "show grants for $uh" | sed 's/$/;/; s/\\/\/g'; done > grants.sql;

Answer (score 0):

The scripts given above give the general idea, but they're inefficient.  They're forking/execing mysql n+1 times.  It can be done in only two calls to mysql

```
mysql ${logininfo} -B -N -e "SELECT CONCAT('\'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\'') from user where user != 'root'" mysql | \
while read uh
do
   echo "SHOW GRANTS FOR ${uh};"
done | mysql ${logininfo} -B -N | sed -e 's/$/;/' > ${outfile}
```

If there are users other than root that you don't want to backup use or and specify user != 'whatever' in the where clause of the first mysql call.