# Backup grant privileges for a selected mysql database

Tags: mysql, database-backups, sql-grant

I have backup the mysql database db1 from a bunch of database hosted on the same server.
Now need to backup only the selected users with privileges who have access to db1 so that I can restore these privileged users to my new server before the db1 restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar problem was already posted on StackOverflow: [Backup MySQL users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597732/backup-mysql-users)

To find users, who have only access to a given database, use this query (given you have sufficient privileges for the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and `mysql` database):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db1';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE db = 'db1';
```

Also, you can view table-specific privileges for a user:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db1';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.tables_priv WHERE db = 'db1';
```